# Extract Objects from Collection<Objects> based on a Map input

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate, predicatebuilder

I have a collection of around 13360 Account objects, something like below

Input Data:

```
Account(id,date,balance,region,cost)
Account("1","2019-07-24","X,"Y","Z")
Account("1","2019-07-24","C,"Y","Z")
Account("1","2019-07-23","X,"D","Z")
Account("1","2019-07-23","X,"Y","f")
Account("1","2019-07-22","X,"s","Z")

Account("2","2019-07-23","X,"A","Z")
Account("2","2019-07-23","X,"Y","d")
Account("2","2019-07-22","d,"Y","Z")
Account("2","2019-07-23","X,"s","Z")

Account("3","2019-07-24","d,"Y","d")

Account("4","2019-07-24","X,"Y","Z")
Account("4","2019-07-23","d,"Y","Z")

Account("5","2019-07-23","X,"d","Z")
Account("5","2019-07-22","X,"Y","Z")
```

Filter criteria:

```
Map<id,date>
(1,2019-07-24), (2,2019-07-23),(5,2019-07-23)
```

RESULT Expected is

```
Account("1","2019-07-24","X,"Y","Z")
Account("1","2019-07-24","C,"Y","Z")

Account("2","2019-07-23","X,"A","Z")
Account("2","2019-07-23","X,"Y","d")
Account("2","2019-07-23","X,"s","Z")

Account("5","2019-07-23","X,"d","Z")
```

Thus I want to retrieve the most recent data for certain accounts

The below code sample just gives me data for the most recent date ie(today's dates) for a certain list of accounts. but for certain accounts, I do not have data for today's date, so I need to retrive the most recent data that is available

```
EntryObject eo = new PredicateBuilder.getEntryObject();
Predicate p = eo.get("id").in(1,2,5).and(eo.get("date").equals(todaysdate))
Collection<Account> coll = accounts.values(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more generic solution to get only the latest entries for a set of `accountIds`:

```
Set<Integer> accountIds = Set.of(1, 2, 5);
List<Account> result = accounts.stream()
        .filter(a -> accountIds.contains(a.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getId, Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getDate, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList())))
        .values().stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.lastEntry().getValue().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First you filter only the required accounts based on the id. After that you group them by id and date, which will give you this intermediate result:

```
{
  1: {
    2019-07-22: [{id: 1, date: 2019-07-22, balance: 'X', region: 's', cost: 'Z'}], 
    2019-07-23: [{id: 1, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'D', cost: 'Z'}, {id: 1, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'Y', cost: 'f'}],
    2019-07-24: [{id: 1, date: 2019-07-24, balance: 'X', region: 'Y', cost: 'Z'}, {id: 1, date: 2019-07-24, balance: 'C', region: 'Y', cost: 'Z'}]
  }, 
  2: {
    2019-07-22: [{id: 2, date: 2019-07-22, balance: 'd', region: 'Y', cost: 'Z'}], 
    2019-07-23: [{id: 2, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'A', cost: 'Z'}, {id: 2, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'Y', cost: 'd'}, {id: 2, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 's', cost: 'Z'}]
  }, 
  5: {
    2019-07-22: [{id: 5, date: 2019-07-22, balance: 'X', region: 'Y', cost: 'Z'}], 
    2019-07-23: [{id: 5, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'd', cost: 'Z'}]
  }
}
```

Finally you use only the values of the resulting map and `flatMap` it to the last value of the grouped TreeMap to get only the list with the latest dates.

The final result will be this:

```
[
  {id: 1, date: 2019-07-24, balance: 'X', region: 'Y', cost: 'Z'}, 
  {id: 1, date: 2019-07-24, balance: 'C', region: 'Y', cost: 'Z'}, 

  {id: 2, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'A', cost: 'Z'}, 
  {id: 2, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'Y', cost: 'd'}, 
  {id: 2, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 's', cost: 'Z'},

  {id: 5, date: 2019-07-23, balance: 'X', region: 'd', cost: 'Z'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `anyMatch` within filteras:

```
List<Account> filteredAccounts = acccounts.stream()
        .filter(acc -> map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(e -> e.getKey().equals(acc.getId())
                        && e.getValue().equals(acc.getDate())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```